# Oracle updateXml "less than sign" as text

Tags: oracle, xmltype, updatexml

I have xml document

```xml
<d>
  <r>a&lt;b</r>
</d>
```

and I want to update it to

```xml
<d>
  <r>a&lt;b or c&gt;d</r>
</d>
```

using **updateXML** statement.

Executing

```
select updateXML(xmltype('<d><r>a&lt;b</r></d>'),
                 '/d/r[1]/text()',
                 'a&lt;b or c&gt;d')
  from dual;
```

returns

```xml
<d>
  <r>a&amp;lt;b or c&amp;gt;d</r>
</d>
```

It is not good because of "&".

Executing

```
select updateXML(xmltype('<d><r>a&lt;b</r></d>'),
                 '/d/r[1]/text()',
                 'a<b or c>d')
  from dual;
```

throws

> ORA-31067 XML nodes must be updated with valid nodes and of the same type.

How can I reach expected result?

**EDIT**: ORA-31067 is raised only in 10g database. It is correct query in 11g.

**EDIT2**: Error raised on 10.2.0.3 version and does not raised on 10.2.0.5. May by it was a bug?

Comment: Does it work with "& l t ;" (with white spaces)?

Comment: No, parser finds '&' and throws same error.

Comment: @Kotodid, what happens if you try `htf.escape_sc('a<b or c>d')` ? BTW what version are you using ? because on 11g it works http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/12128

Comment: `htf.escape_sc` just replaces <> to &lt;&gt;, so I get first sample in my question. DB version is 10g.

Comment: @Kotodid, isn't that what you want ?

Comment: I want to get <r>a&lt;b or c&gt;d</r>, but not <r>a&amp;lt;b or c&amp;gt;d</r>.

Comment: " May by it was a bug?"  If code fails on earlier versions and works on later versions then yes, most likely it's a bug.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this ugly workaround:

```
select dbms_xmlgen.convert(updateXML(xmltype('<d><r>a&lt;b</r></d>'),
                 '/d/r[1]/text()',
                 'a&lt;b or c&gt;d').getStringVal(), 1)
from dual;
```